# Oracle APEX interactive grid duplicate column value validation

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In an interactive grid, what is the best way to validate for duplicate values in a column. I have a requirement to check if a date column exists for more than one row. Is there an api or a declarative way to not allow more than one row with the same date.

APEX version : 20.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found this neat example at https://lschilde.blogspot.com/2020/04/interactive-grid-validation-duplicated.html very useful